# Flask Socketio in async_mode="threading" error on disconnect

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using "flask-socketio" package in my project with "threading" async_mode option and everything is working but on disconnection it throws an Exception.

```
Server initialized for threading.
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
Server initialized for threading.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 880-792-448
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0
connect
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"dSzvR3LXlDUexsWOAAAB"}
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 1
dygUQeczUBlQ_1ScAAAA: Unexpected error "", closing connection
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2022 11:09:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AndriiO18\projects\socketio-threading\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 335, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\AndriiO18\projects\socketio-threading\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327, in execute
    write(b"")
  File "C:\Users\AndriiO18\projects\socketio-threading\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 252, in write
    assert status_set is not None, "write() before start_response"
AssertionError: write() before start_response
```

Even if I remove "connect" event handler it still throws this Error on disconnection.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="threading", engineio_logger=True)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return "root"


@socketio.on("connect")
def connect():
    print("connect")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

requirement.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.2
bidict==0.22.0
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
dnspython==2.2.1
eventlet==0.33.1
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.1
greenlet==1.1.3.post0
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
python-dotenv==0.21.0
python-engineio==4.3.4
python-socketio==5.7.1
requests==2.28.1
simple-websocket==0.8.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.12
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wsproto==1.2.0
```

I'm using windows 11 and Python 3.10.6.
I tried to use "Postman" and "socket.io-client" but results are same.
Will be appreciated for any help or advice in fixing it.

Thanks.

Here the [link to the repo](https://github.com/andreyohiienko/socketio-threading) if needed.

Comment: read https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html i think you need eventlet or gevent installed, and maybe monkey patched too for your case. also, check version compatibility at the bottom of https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html